# Capset problem but considering differences with bounded support

Tags: additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-progression

For any dimension $D\ge 1$, we define the homomorphism $\phi: \Bbb{Z}^D\to (\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z})^D; \xi\mapsto \xi+3\Bbb{Z}^D$.

Given a set $A \subset \{0,1,2\}^D$, we define $S_A$ to be the set of $v \in \{0,1,2\}^D$ where $$\phi(A)\cap \phi(A+v) \cap \phi(A+2v) \neq \emptyset.$$In other words, $S_A$ is the set of vectors which map to a common difference of a $3$-term progression $P\subset \phi(A)$.

Let $F(D,k)$ denote the size of the largest $A \subset \{0,1,2\}^D$ such that $S_A\setminus\{0^D\}$ lacks any $v = (v_1,\dots,v_D)\in \{0,1,2\}^D$ where $v_i\neq 0$ for at most $k$ indices $i$.

**Question:** If $k=k(D)$ grows slower than $D$, can the polynomial method still prove that $F(D,k) \ll (3-\epsilon)^D$? For concreteness, can one show $F(D,D/\log D)$ is exponentially sparse?

If this is too hard, I'd also be interested to know if one can show $F(D,D/\log D) \ll 3^D/D^\delta$.

**Motivation:** I am curious about this due to connections to the Hales Jewett numbers. By considering the set $A_* \subset \{0,1,2\}^D$ of words $a$ where $|a^{-1}(t) -D/3|\le \sqrt{D}$ for each $t =0,1,2$, we get a positive density set which does not contain any combinatorial lines with support $>2\sqrt{D}$. So I want to know if it's hopeless to try to get an improved lower bound for HJ by proving $F(D,2\sqrt{D})$ is large, and then intersecting those constructions with $A_*$.

Comment: So, $F(D,1)\ge F(D,2)\ge\ldots$, right? Then why consider any $k$ different from 1?

Comment: To apply it to HJ, you'd need to consider $k\approx \sqrt{D}$. But I see your point, I'll edit to correct my question.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, in retrospect I was being stupid. Obviously $F(n,D)\le 3^n (r_3(\Bbb{F}_3^D)/3^D)$ (for $D\le n$); this because you look at the $D$-dimensional cosets, and note that their intersections with $A$ correspond to $3$-AP-free subsets of $\Bbb{F}_3^D$. Thus you can deduce a bound of shape $F(n,D) \le (.99)^D 3^n$.

This is fairly strong, it answers some of my questions, and shows that it’s impossible to get a Hales-Jewett construction in the way I wanted.