# Progressions in finite fields with bounded hamming weight

Tags: additive-combinatorics, coding-theory, arithmetic-progression

Given $k\ge 2$ and an additive set $S$ (understood to live some implicit group $G$), define $$\Delta_k(S) := \left\{ d \in G: \bigcap_{i=1}^k (S+i\cdot d) \neq \emptyset \right\} $$(i.e., this is the set of common differences $d$ of $k$-term progressions $P \subset S$).

Consider $V :=\Bbb{F}_3^n$, and fix some basis $E= \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}\subset V$. Furthermore, for $w\ge 1$, define the ball $B_w$ to be the set of all non-zero linear combinations of at most $w$ vectors from $E$.

Finally, define $F(n,w)$ to be the cardinality of the largest set $A\subset V$ such that $\Delta_3(A)$ is disjoint from $B_w$. I had previously asked about this function $F(n,w)$ in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429816/capset-problem-but-considering-differences-with-bounded-support), but I have a more focused question here.

We have that $F(n,1) = (2/3) 3^n = \Omega(|\Bbb{F}_3^n|)$ (fix a homomorphism $\phi:V\to \Bbb{F}_3$ such that $\ker(\phi)\cap E$ is empty, and then take $A:= V\setminus \ker(\phi)$). But I'm not sure if this is a fluke, due to the existence of dense "Hamming codes" of distance 2... So I'd like to know what happens for larger (constant) values of $w$.

**Question:** Is $F(n,2)= o(3^n)$? If not, what about $F(n,100)$? If yes (to either question), then I'd also be curious if analogous things hold, if we consider longer progressions in finite fields of higher characteristic.

Comment: I may be missing something but if $S+i\cdot d$ is a translate of the whole set $S$ how is the set of progressions $P$ a subset of $S$? $P$ contains $S$ when $i=0,$ and is usually larger than $S$, no?

Comment: for $d \in \Delta_k(S)$, the relevant intersection is non-empty, and in particular contains some element $x$. but then defining $P = \{x-d,x,x+d,\dots,x+(k-2)\cdot d\}$, we have that $P\subset S$. clearly, $d$ is a common difference of $P$, as desired.